# How to check if file has special characters such as CR in linux?

Tags: linux, unix

How to check if file has special characters such as CR in linux?

I have some files that may include special characters. I Know that if I do dos2unix, it will fix the issue. But I recall there is a way to actually view the file and see/print the special characters in it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `file`, e.g.

```
$ file test_unix.txt 
test.txt: ASCII text

$ file test_dos.txt 
test.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```